# Can we create an object without using the new keyword in java?

Tags: java, oop

(I was asked this in my interview)

I said yes but when he asked  to do it I wasnt able to

Comment: Seems like a silly question to me. What insight does the interview hope to gain by asking this? Would `int[] x = { 0 };` count? An array is an object...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. Also share what you already investigated on this topic.

Comment: `Double df = 3.14159` would also do it

Comment: As a gentle nudge, btw: I found the linked duplicate by googling the exact text of this question's subject line. It was the top result.

Comment: `"x = " + Math.random()`